# How to rotate multiple images?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content-image").each(function() {
    var angle = randAngle();
    $(".content-image").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)");
  });
});

function randAngle() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="content-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
<img class="content-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
```

But it rotates all the images with the same angle. How can I have a different angle for each image?

Comment: use `$(this).css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)");`

Comment: @MarkBaijens It's works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$(".content-image").css("transform"...
```

to

```
$(this).css("transform"...
```

so that it applies the transform to each image in the loop one at a time

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` within the `each()` loop selects the current element. Changed your random to a 0-360 number for demonstration purpose.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content-image").each(function() {
        var angle = randAngle();
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + "deg)");
    });
});

function randAngle() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="content-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=Stack" />
<img class="content-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=Overflow" />
```